# Google Street View: Horizontal to Vertical FOV conversion

Tags: ios, google-maps, math, google-street-view

Consider a Google Street View panorama. How to convert horizontal Field Of View (FOV) to the vertical one and vice versa?

First, I have tried this formula, supposing that projection is spherical:

```
VFOW = 2 * arctg(h/w * tg(HFOV / 2))
```

Where h and w - is height and width of panorama image, VFOW and HFOV - is vertical and horizontal FOV. But this formula gives very inaccurate result. As documentation tells,
[Street View Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#CreatingPanoramas/)
Google Street View uses equirectangular projection. **I need you help to derive a conversion formula for this case.**

---

Why do I need this? The problem arose while I were creating an iOS application. In this application some static panorama previews are presented to the user. When user click on such a preview, GMSPanoramaView is opened. **The problem is to obtain exactly the same preview as the panorama shown by GMSPanoramaView.**

[Google Street View Image API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/#url_parameters) allows to specify a horizontal FOV. While [GMSPanoramaCamera](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_panorama_camera#a64dcd1302c83a54f2d068cbb19ea5cef) FOV is:

> encompassed by the larger dimension (width or height) of the view in degree

My app supports portrait orientation. In this case the larger dimension is height.

Comment: Formula seems to work good, I just forgot "&" in URL request :) Now I have problems with different pitch on GMSPanoramaView and on static image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula in question is all right.